# How to pass ID when deleting row in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid

I'm using jqGrid and have setup an action handler where I want the user to be able to delete a row.  The callback specified in the URL is being called, but I can't figure out how to pass the row ID to the URL handler so I know which row to delete.

Anyone have a solution to this?

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'datahandler',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['Name','Description', 'Data (Abbreviated)', 'Actions'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:300, resizeable:true},
            {name:'description',index:'description', width:300, resizeable:true},
            {name:'data',index:'data', width:600, resizeable:true},
            {name : 'actions', sortable:false, index: 'actions', formatter:'actions',
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true,
                    editbutton: false,
                    delOptions: { url: 'deleterow' }
                               }}
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: 'name',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"PVSyst Data",
    });
    $("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which format exactly you use to fill the grid and which rowid you use. Typical error exist if the data wrong filled and the values 1, 2, 3 will be used instead of rowids which you want to see on the server side. In any way the above code will use HTTP POST request to the URL `"deleterow"` specified in `delOptions`. The data have the format described in the documentation of `delGridRow` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server2)). For example if the id of deleted row is `"123"` then the data posted to the URL `"deleterow"` will be

```
oper=del&id=123
```

You need just implement reading of the `id` parameter on the server side. If you want to rename the name of parameter from `id` to any other text like `myId` then you can use [jqGrid option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) `prmNames: { id: "myId" }`. After that the posted data will look like

```
oper=del&myId=123
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the comment. I am not seeing the id sent down in either the URL or as data in the stream.  Is there anything extra I need in my HTML to enable the ID to be sent?

Comment: @fredbasset: Nothing additional to do. By the way I added `'actions'` column which you defined in a grid and I could see in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) that HTTP POST request done and the body of the request contains `oper=del&id=123`. I recommend you to trace HTTP traffic with Fiddler, Developer Tools of IE, Chrome or any other tools.

Comment: Update : I am now getting the oper and id through as form data.  However the id is the numeric index of the table row, what I really want is the name of the first column of the row.  Any ideas how I get the grid to send me that?

Comment: @fredbasset: I wrote you that the problem with usage of 1, 2, 3... values as rowid exist typically if you fill the grid in a wrong form. You asked in the question "how to pass the row ID to the URL". You can examine the grid and you would that `<tr>` elements of the grid have `id` attributes equal 1,2,3. It's the rowids. If the data from `'name'` column **really unique** and there are no duplicates between you can insert `key: true` property in `colModel` for `'name'` column. If you would still have problems you should attend your question with test JSON data returned from the server.

Comment: Thank you!  The key:true was the attribute I needed.  Good work.